# Drop-down menus in MS Project 2013 disappeared

Tags: ms-project-2013

In one of my MS Project 2013 files, the drop down menus appear when I hover over the column headers in the Task Sheet view. In another file and new files, the drop down menu option does not appear in any views for any column headers.

How could I get the drop down arrow back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with the menus do this.

**View** >> **Filter** >> **Display AutoFilter** .... (shorthand for below)

Click on the **View** tab.

Then look for the **Filter** drop down. It's about in the middle and has a little funnel next to it.

Click on the drop down arrow.

Almost at the bottom of that menu, next row to the last, should be a selection for **Display AutoFilter**.

Click on that and the auto filter arrows should get turned back on.

Hope that helps! (please mark whichever answer you find the most suitable as the answer)

Comment: Much better answer than using a macro. Thanks Jack.

Answer (score 0):

File >> Options >> Advanced >> Set AutoFilter on for New Projects.

If your project exists and therefore is no longer new, press Alt + F11 to bring up the VBA editor and copy/paste this macro:

```
Sub autofilter()
  ActiveProject.autofilter = True
End Sub
```

Click somewhere in the macro and press F5 to execute the macro.